# How do I create a document object that I can pass to a jquery plugin from React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently working on a project to convert an old jQuery grid extension into a react component. The jQuery extension is a grid from another internal team that makes quite a few references to the document object to create elements, query elements, etc. I was able to get the grid to render into a react component but with that I run into issues because the document object is null. Now I need to be clear I am new to React and understand that I need to get jQuery working on the Virtual Dom. After searching around it isn't obvious to me that there even is a document parallel in React. Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery can work with DOM built by React. Just run your JQuery extension when React mounted component (in componentDidMount method for React <=15 or in useEffect hook in latest React).